# Cordova Inappbrowser Android responsive website is opening in Desktop view

Tags: cordova, android-webview, cordova-plugins, phonegap, inappbrowser

Everyone, I am creating an application where I open up every external link in an in-app browser. Now while opening that link it is opening in Desktop view in a Zoomed out manner.
I am using like this - var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://money.cnn.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');

** Though is website has viewport enabled and responsive in nature, I am unable to load it in responsive view over my App's in-app browser.

Is it possible to load the responsive content in inAppBrowser like Normal Browser behaves? please help me in this. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Most websites use the user-agent to determine whether to return the mobile site. I believe you can use [cordova's OverrideUserAgent preference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#preference) to adjust this as needed, i.e:

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 My Browser" />
```